# After shrink the error still occurs

Tags: 2013, sql-server

When I try to save the aspx page an error occures. It says "....It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web".

At SQL Server Man. Studio, I select WSS_Content, Tasks>Shrink>File, File Type:Log, Reorganize pages before releasing unused space Shrink file to min 5 MB.

I did the same think to the Sharepoint_Config too. But the error still occures.

The files sizes(Path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA):

Sharepoint Config:113MB

Sharepoint Config Log: 693MB

WSS Content:48000MB

WSS Content log:5MB

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?Thank you

Comment: Not really seeing the relation between saving a page and database shrinking...

Comment: Can you tell if this page is custom page. why do you do shrink of DB?

Comment: I solved it. Don't know how but it works now.Yes it is a custom page. I researced about the error and it says that the reason is WSS Content logs capacity is full.